# Buy Get Offer Calculation?

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic, percentages

I have some clarification regarding any equation to do some logic like

Buy 2 Get 3 Offer with repeat (means if i buy 4 then 6 to be off)

If i add 2 quantities of product to cart then another 3 number of quantities are 10% off for next 3 products

it is some thing like 
Product price =100
product discount = 10% so it is 10

Upto 2 product it is 200$

```
when i add 3rd product it cost reduce to 
(3*100)-10 = 290$
for 4th one
(4*100)-20 = 380$
for 5th one 
(5*100)-30 = 470$
```

but 6 and 7 should add original price because of repeat

```
ex: original price => discounted price
1,2 => 3,4,5

6,7 => 8,9,10

11,12 => 13,14,15
```

.. so on

Example

```
$buy=2,$get=3
$current_quantity = 13;
$total_quantity = $buy+$get;
```

for 13

i want the following series as count

```
example 3,4,5,8,9,10,13 total 7 so discount 1300-70 = 1230$

if buy 1 get 3 with 10% off means 13 

2,3,4,6,7,8,10,11,12 total 9 so discount  1300-90 = 1210$
```

not sure how to get this desired result in a minimal efficient manner any help or equation will be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $n \geq 0$ is the number of products and $p$ is the price of the product.

If $n \equiv 0 \,(mod \,5)$ ($n = 0,5,10,15,\ldots)$, then $\frac{2}{5}n$ have the original price and $\frac{3}{5}n$ have 10% discount, so the total is 
$$T = \big[\frac{2}{5}n\big]\cdot p + \big[\frac{3}{5}n\big]\cdot (p \cdot 0.9)$$

If $n \equiv 1 \,(mod \,5)$ ($n = 1,6,11,16,\ldots)$, then $n-1 \equiv 0 \, (mod \, 5),$ so 
$$T = \big[\frac{2}{5}(n-1) + 1\big] \cdot p + \big[\frac{3}{5}(n-1) \big] \cdot (p \cdot 0.9)$$

If $n \equiv 2 \, (mod \, 5)$  ($n = 2,7,12,17,\ldots)$, then $n-2 \equiv 0 \, (mod \, 5)$, so
$$T = \big[\frac{2}{5}(n-2) + 2\big] \cdot p + \big[\frac{3}{5}(n-2) \big] \cdot (p \cdot 0.9)$$

If $n \equiv 3 \, (mod \, 5)$ ($n = 3, 8, 13, 18, \ldots)$, then

$$T = \big[\frac{2}{5}(n-3) + 2\big] \cdot p + \big[\frac{3}{5}(n-3) + 1 \big] \cdot (p \cdot 0.9)$$

The last case, $ n \equiv 4 \, (mod \, 5)$ ($n = 4, 9, 14, 19, \ldots$) is

$$T = \big[\frac{2}{5}(n-4) + 2\big] \cdot p + \big[\frac{3}{5}(n-4)+ 2 \big] \cdot (p \cdot 0.9).$$

I don't know if this is efficient, but in simple terms: given the total number of products that were bought, divide it by $5$, and look at the residue, which can only be $0,1,2,3,4$. Depending on the residue, apply the corresponding formula to get the total price.

**The general case:** Buy $x$, and get the next $y$ with discount $d$, $0 < d < 1 \, (d=.1 \implies 10$%, $d=.25 \implies 25$%, etc...).

If $n$ is the number of products, $p$ is the price of the product, and $0 \leq r < x+y \,$ the remainder of dividing $\frac{n}{x+y}$, then the total is

$$T = \big[ \frac{x \cdot (n-r)}{x+y} + r \big] \cdot p \, + \big[ \frac{y \cdot (n-r)}{x+y} \big] \cdot (1-d)\cdot p, \text{ if } r \leq x $$
or

$$T = \big[ \frac{x \cdot (n-r)}{x+y} + x \big] \cdot p \, + \big[ \frac{y \cdot (n-r)}{x+y} + (r-x)\big] \cdot (1-d)\cdot p, \text{ if } r > x.$$